# How to solve telethon UnboundLocalError

Tags: python, variables, telethon

I get this error on the last line of my code. If anyone has encountered with the same problem, I'll be glad to share with me on how to solve it.
The source code is telethon based and is full. The execution is also successful but when wanna give response to userid it gives the UnboundLocalError.

The codes:

```
@client.on(events.NewMessage(incoming=True, from_users=(723428565, 677543378)))
async def _(event):
    if event.fwd_from:
        return
    url = "http://www.google.com" 
    if event.reply_to_msg_id and "allow" in event.raw_text:
        previous_message = await event.get_reply_message()
        previous_message_text = previous_message.message
        if previous_message.media:
            downloaded_file_name = await client.download_media(
                previous_message,
                path, 
            )
            surl = "{}/searchbyimage/upload".format(url)
            multipart = {
                "encoded_image": (
                    downloaded_file_name,
                    open(downloaded_file_name, "rb"),
                ),
                "image_content": "",
            }
            google_rs_response = requests.post(
                surl, files=multipart, allow_redirects=False
            )
            the_location = google_rs_response.headers.get("Location")
            os.remove(downloaded_file_name)
        else:
            previous_message_text = previous_message.message
            surl = "{}/searchbyimage?image_url={}"
            request_url = surl.format(url, previous_message_text)
            google_rs_response = requests.get(request_url, allow_redirects=False)
            the_location = google_rs_response.headers.get("Location")
        headers = {
            "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:58.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/58.0"
        }
        response = requests.get(the_location, headers=headers)
        soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, "html.parser")
        bro = soup.find_all("div", {"class": "r5a77d"})[0]
        lol = bro.find("a")
        url + lol.get("href")
        final = lol.text
    await event.edit(
        event.chat_id, final.replace("me", "")
    )
```

Error :

```
Line 42: UnboundLocalError: local variable 'final' referenced before assignment
```

Comment: Please include the _full_ stack trace. It's much easier and faster to see which line causes your error from the stack trace than to hunt through your code to find where you have referenced the variable `text` before assigning anything to it.

Comment: Please post a [mre] that people can run to reproduce your code. Please also take the [tour] and read [ask] and the helpful links therein. [How to debug small programs.](//ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) is also helpful. Welcome to Stack Overflow!

Comment: Also, please don't delete [your question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66100633/how-to-solve-unboundlocalerror-error-in-telethon) and repost the same one...

Answer (score 1):

You are defining the variable `text = lol.text` inside the if block `if "allow" in event.raw_text:`

So it looks like your condition wasn't met, and the variable `text` was never defined. So when you tried to access it `await event.edit(event.chat_id, text.replace("me", ""))` you got an error

Comment: I edited the variable name to final in order to avoid misleading. See, it's a feature in a bot and I want it to return answer only if the word "allow" exists in the specified userid message. So that must be in the if block. Also for the last line, it's outside of the block and if I put it inside of the block no response will be returned and also no errors will be shown.I tried what you said but again gives errors. If you have any idea on how to solve it please say it clearly with the corrected form of the wrong part of the code mentioned.  Thanks a lot for your help. 